What is the source of Rambam's cosmology?
In the Mishneh Torah third section of Yesodei a geocentric world is described with a number of spheres containing stars that revolve around the Earth due to the motion of the spheres that contain them. Are there any sources in Chazal where we see a similar world described or is Rambam basing this on Greek astronomy?

By me, as a rule, Judaism doesn’t have any distinctive scientific views (including the calendar). Whatever rabbis taught throughout centuries, was picked up from surrounding cultures. Regarding your question, Rambam's cosmology is largely based on the works of Aristotle (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On_the_Heavens) and influenced by Islamic philosophers.

I've heard it was Aristotle but haven't verified (hence the comment).

Not quite Aristotle, not quite Plato as discussed here https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/maimonides/#Cre

See my answer here, the 2nd answer at: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/6162/science-of-the-rishonim-on-celestial-spheres/146494
